# Как перенести на новую строку не возвращая каретку?

Tags: c++

В `c++` перенос строки осуществляется через `\n` но он так-же переносит каретку в исходное состояние, пример:

```
Первый текст
Перенесенный текст
```

А мне требуется что-бы каретка оставалась в исходном состоянии:

```
Первый текст
            Перенесенный текст
```

Я знаю что такая система есть в ассемблере, можно ли это сделать без помощи функций?

Comment: Перенести текст ГДЕ? Если это терминал, то CR (0x0D) выполняет именно это - опускает курсор вниз на одну строку, LF (0x0A) - помещает курсор в первую позицию текущей строки, их комбинация - переводит курсор в первую позицию следующей строки. Однако в настройках терминала запросто может стоять опция добавлять автоматически к коду CR код LF...

Comment: @Akina Вообще-то наоборот - `\r` гонит курсор в начало строки, `\n` - переводит вниз.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что просто так не получится, потому что даже открытие устройства `"con:"` в бинарном режиме ничего не дает; скорее всего, это - преобразование `\n` как возврата каретки и перевода строки - встроено прямо в консоль...

Comment: @Harry Да, пардон... чёта задумался. Но суть с того не меняется.

Comment: Кстати, покажите, как это вы делаете в ассемблере? Или вас интересует вывод в DOS? Просто там, где отработает в ассемблере - можно написать и на С++.

Comment: нет обычная консоль windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о выводе на стандартный вывод в Windows, то в рамках стандартного С++ решения нет. Стандартный вывод является текстовым потоком, а он всегда транслирует LF в пару CR-LF (т.е. `\n` в `\r\n`). В дополнение к этому сама системная консоль может еще делать свою трансляцию.

Системно-зависимыми средствами в Windows 10 такого эффекта можно достичь, выключив трансляцию на уровне стандартной библиотеки, т.е. переведя стандартный вывод в бинарный режим

```
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <io.h>  

_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
```

а также дополнительно на уровне Windows-консоли

```
#include <windows.h> 

HANDLE hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD mode;
GetConsoleMode(hCon, &mode);
SetConsoleMode(hCon, mode | DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN);
```

Последнее требует использования Windows 10 SDK. Возможно это означает, что в более ранних версиях Windows этого делать не нужно, т.е. консоль своей трансляции не делает. (В более ранних SDK не объявлено константы `DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN`.)

Эффект влияет как на вывод через стандартную библиотеку С, так и на вывод через стандартную библиотеку С++.